# Image scroll between <head> tags, can I put it in an external?

Tags: javascript, image

I am using an image scroller within Javascript, this is the code:

```
var step=1
function slideShow()
{
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
if (step<3)
step++
else
step=1
//call function "slideit()" every 2.0 seconds
setTimeout("slideShow()",2000)
}
slideShow()
```

It is required that this following code goes between the  tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var image1=new Image()
image1.src="images/image1.png"
var image2=new Image()
image2.src="images/image2.png"
var image3=new Image()
image3.src="images/image3.png"
var image4=new Image()
image4.src="images/image4.png"
var image5=new Image()
image5.src="images/image5.png"
//-->
</script>
```

Now, I have other Javascript files within an external js file. I have tried putting the whole code in with the others and hoping it carries with the  tag, but it doesn't work.
I have also tried adding it to an external one by itself, this also doesn't work.

I am sure it is something obvious, but I cannot think what.
Anyone know?

I'd like to have all my JavaScript in JS docs.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the code you're trying to add look like?

Comment: The code that I wanted added to an external file is the top one. It is to go between the <head> tags but I would like it external if it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

To load your content from an external .JS file, just save the content in a file like `myJs.js` and then include it in your `<head>` like so:

```
<script src="myJs.js" type="text/javscript" />
```